# If apt-get was replaced by just apt

Tags: command-line, apt

and I update/upgrade by

`apt update`

then

```
apt upgrade
```

what has replaced:

```
apt-get autoremove ?
```

As near as I can tell there is no

```
apt autoremove
```

command?

Answer (score 3):

You can use either of these commands.

`apt` gives a bit more information, like a progress bar.

`apt` becomes default in Ubuntu 16.04. But still `apt-get` is usable.

There is no much difference how both work.

And there is `apt autoremove` in newer versions of `apt`.

`apt autoremove` [has been added since version `1.1~exp9`](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.2.7/changelog).

In Ubuntu 16.04 version `1.2.7` is installed at the moment.

Comment: Maybe i wasn;'t clear.  Im asking what the apt equivalent of autoremove is.

Comment: The equivalent is `apt autoremove` but it is not implemented in a version of `apt` that is installed in 14.04. But it is implemented in 16.04.

Comment: in 15.10 I get: chris@FILESERVER:~$ sudo apt autoremove
[sudo] password for chris:
E: Invalid operation autoremove

Comment: In 16.04 it works OK.

Comment: do you mean 15.10?  Because It doesn't work in 15.10

Comment: I mean 16.04. I fixed it.