# apt-get being replaced with apt?

Tags: apt, 16.04

I was just reviewing this question: [How do I fix a lot of broken packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766819/how-do-i-fix-a-lot-of-broken-packages)

And I saw the comment by @HoussemGuesmi.

He said, "use `apt`, as `apt-get` is being replaced with `apt` on 16.04"

**Is this really true?** I couldn't find evidence of this on Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you can use both `apt` & `apt-get`, while `apt` has received a lot of developer love in the past weeks/month.

Therefore, `apt` now comes with a progress bar, coloring, etc.

It does not fully replace `apt-get` so far, but will most likely in the future.  So in the long-term it might make sense to get used to `apt` as well and not rely only on `apt-get`.

In addition, please see the question [If apt-get was replaced by just apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747480/if-apt-get-was-replaced-by-just-apt), as it covers this topic already.

Comment: @AndroidDev to add to the above answer it will for sure being there until EOL of 16.04 which is in 2021 so nothing to worry yet about.